# Understanding ということでもあって

Tags: grammar

> 同時に部隊全員の援護を担当するその役割は、部隊全員の状況に目を配っている**ということでもあって**、面倒見のいいライデンにはうってつけの役目だ。ライデン自身は絶対に認めないが。

86─エイティシックス─Ep.2 ─ラン・スルー・ザ・バトルフロント─〈上〉
安里アサト

ライデン is a person’s name. Is the bold part roughly the same as ということがあって? Does the bold part indicate "it is possible that…"?

Comment: It's just the te-form of である, the literary copula. cf. 私は学生でもある ("I am also a student").

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not the same as ということがあって, rather is literally *meaning also that...*

Here XはYということだ/である is a pattern for *X means Y*, and も is added for *also*. Overall the sentence will be like *The role ...., meaning/implying also that one must keep an eye for everyone in the team, is a right job for Ryden who...*